# debian/control doesn't list any binary package

Tags: application-development, compiling, packaging, debuild

I am running the `debuild` in order to generate the `<source.changes>` file to later upload my package using

```
dput ppa:myusername/mypackagename <source.changes>
```

as briefly mentioned [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading).

I recieve the following warning and errors:

```
$ debuild
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of screen-generator_0.3.orig.tar.gz, screen-generator_0.3.orig.tar.bz2,
screen-generator_0.3.orig.tar.lzma,  screen-generator_0.3.orig.tar.xz or screen-generator.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n) y 
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: source package screen-generator
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.3-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by root <root@computer>
 dpkg-source --before-build screen-generator
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Package' in input data in general section of control info file
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Version' in input data in general section of control info file
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Architecture' in input data in general section of control info file
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Description' in input data in general section of control info file
dpkg-source: error: screen-generator/debian/control doesn't list any binary package
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build screen-generator gave error exit status 255
```

What do I need to do to avoid this error or generate a `<source.changes>` file?

My package is called `screen-generator` and my `debian/control` file contains the following

```
Source: screen-generator
Package: screen-generator
Version: 0.3
Standard-Version: 0.3
Section: base
Maintainer: my_mail@gmail.com <my_mail@gmail.com>
XSBC-Original-Maintainer: Name <my_mail@gmail.com>
Priority: optional
Architecture: any
Vcs-Bzr: lp:ubuntu/screen-generator
Homepage: https://github.com/boddhissattva/screen-generator
Vcs-Git: https://github.com/boddhissattva/screen-generator
Description: 
 screen-generator generates screen configuration files and launches screen by providing a chain of commands
```

Comment: What is in your `mypackagename/debian/control`?

Comment: Thread updated with control file.

Comment: It looks OK. Weird.

Comment: Did you create the file manually? Weird looking is `Standard-Version`, should be `Standards-Version`.

Comment: I still have the same error if I add  the missing  `tar.gz` file

Comment: Had the same issue. If the `debian` dir is part of the source tree, set the contents of `source/version` to `3.0 (native)` (not `quilt`) **and** ensure the version number (as per `changelog`) does not contain a dash (`0.3` or `0.3.1` is OK, but not `0.3-1`): otherwise the toolchain will assume that project maintainer and Debian maintainer are two different people (or groups of people), and insist on what it thinks it the proper workflow: tarball with upstream source, debian files (and patches, if any) kept separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must reorder you control file in this way:

```
Source: screen-generator
Section: base
Priority: optional
Maintainer: my_mail@gmail.com <my_mail@gmail.com>

Package: screen-generator
Version: 0.3
Standards-Version: 0.3
XSBC-Original-Maintainer: Name <my_mail@gmail.com>
Architecture: any
Vcs-Bzr: lp:ubuntu/screen-generator
Homepage: https://github.com/boddhissattva/screen-generator
Vcs-Git: https://github.com/boddhissattva/screen-generator
Description: short description
 screen-generator generates screen configuration files and launches screen by providing a chain of commands
```

Note the blank line between Maintainer and Package, this is really needed. Once you do that re-run debuild and your issue with "unknown information field" must be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [debian package documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Source), the `debian/control` has to have two paragraphs:

1. The **general paragraph** (the first one, for the source package)
2. The fields in the **binary package paragraphs**

Comment: Would you flag your answer as the accepted one, because this what works for you. Packaging is really hard when trying to learn it alone :) .